# What does the phrase "shape up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrases, phrasal-verbs

What does the phrase "shape up" mean in the following sentence from the description (not available online) of the game "Griddie Islands"

> Help these tropical getaways **shape up**.

Here is a description of the game from a different source:

> Griddie Islands is a classic puzzle game with arcade elements, in
> which you need to make a small island with different geometric shapes,
> gradually increasing their level and earning more money. ([Apk Vision](https://apkvision.com/games/casual/griddie-islands-56457/))

Answer (score 3):

It's a pun: to shape up means to behave yourself. Parents tell kids: You need to shape up. Or bosses tell lazy employees that.

So, you have to make the "shapes behave". Put them into some kind of order.

Comment: As clarification, "shape up" means more generally "to improve".  If someone is misbehaving, the phrase will be used on them to "improve themselves" by no longer misbehaving.  But "shape up" can also be used outside of the context of naughty children and lazy employees.  The military wants their recruits to "shape up" by becoming physically stronger and develop teamwork, for instance.  Or I might want to "shape up" by losing weight.